# Different table layouts

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

I have a table that looks like this:

```
|| id  | year |  userCode  |  jan  |  feb  |  ... ... ... |  dec  ||
```

The columns jan - dec holds value (money) data in it. I want it to look like this:

```
||id  |  year  |  month  |  userCode  |  value ||
```

Here's the thing: I can have two values for the same userCode in the same month (and I need them both), so I can't just use SUM. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why can't you use SUM? Why did you drop your ID column?

Comment: Do you want to design the tables, then my answer is below. If you want a query for that, then you may have to look into something else...

Comment: my bad, I forgot id on the second table...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server 2005+ you can easily do this using the [`UNPIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function which transforms data from columns into rows.

The code would be similar to this:

```
select id, year, month, usercode, value
from yourtable
unpivot
(
  value
  for month in (Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May,
                Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct,
                Nov, Dec)
) unpiv
```

Once the data in the rows, then you can perform any type of aggregation needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with two tables...

One table with Years and Months in it

### YearMonths

|| Id | Year | Month | UserCode ||

### YearMonthsValues

|| Id | YearMonthId | Value ||

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with union all:

```
select year, month, userCode, jan, 'jan' as which as value from t union all
select year, month, userCode, feb, 'feb' as which as value from t union all
. . .
select year, month, userCode, dec, 'dec' as which as value from t
```

I added an extra column `which` so you would know where the data came from.